# Log4net not writing exact line number in log file even using ex.stacktrace in PRODUCTION server

Tags: c#

Log4net not writing exact line number in log file even using ***ex.stacktrace*** in **PRODUCTION** server

Comment: I would assume since it is PROD server, you have release build deployed, which won't have `.pdb` files, which makes it impossible to contain line numbers.

Comment: Need to check, thanks for info